# How to check if gzip level has changed before calling ob_end_clean() and how to handle that case

Tags: php, buffer, gzip

i've got this function which dumps all buffers

```
    /**
     * Dump output buffers before starting output
     *
     * @return bool True unless an error occurs
     */
    protected function _dump_buffers() {
            $result = true;
            while ( ob_get_level() ) {
                    $result &= ob_end_clean();
            }
            return $result;
    }
```

problem is, ob_end_clean() [throws an error if the compression level change](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php#103817) so what can i do to fight this and how could i still dump the buffers?Is there a better way to do this?
I guess i could

```
    protected function _dump_buffers() {
            $result = true;
            $level = ini_get('zlib.output_compression');
            while ( ini_get('zlib.output_compression') === $level && ob_get_level() ) {
                    $result &= ob_end_clean();
            }
            return $result;
    }
```

to avoid the error but i would not dump the buffer.